# formating a list of files in directory in JSON format

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am required to list all files in a directory in JSON format which will be passed on to jade template. How can I do that asynchronously?

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', {
    title: 'Advanced Solution Writer',
    pdf: JSON.parse( /*need to get all files inside directory foo*/)});

});
```

Can I write something like anonymous function that returns list of files in it? Here is a piece of code that I tried which is not working. I am new to node.js

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', {
    title: 'Advanced Solution Writer',
    pdf: JSON.parse(

        function() {
          const fs = require('fs');
          fs.readdir("./public/pdf", function (err, files) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
            }
            return files;
          })
        }
    )});

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it inside out. The asynchronous approach requires you to start by reading the file list, and in the callback, you can render the page.

Roughly like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  fs.readdir("./public/pdf", function (err, files) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      throw err; // To generate a 500 internal server error
    }
    res.render('index', {
      title: 'Advanced Solution Writer',
      pdf: JSON.parse(files)
    });
  });
});
```

I also recommend looking into [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) as an alternative to callbacks. Promises can make the flow of your code clearer and simpler.

Answer (score 1):

use `res.render` inside the `readdir` callback:

```
var fs = require('fs');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    fs.readdir("./public/pdf", function(err, files) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }

      res.render('index', {
         title: 'Advanced Solution Writer',
         pdf: JSON.parse(files)
      });
   });
});
```